# How can I fix my right column in jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables, fixed

In my datatable I fixed the right column

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({
     "data":{{ data }},
     "scrollX": true,
     "fixedColumns":   {
        rightColumns: 1
      },
```

But when I change the amount of entries to show, or the pagination  I get a strange display error.

I tried to solve the error like this:

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
table.fixedColumns().relayout();
```

and also like this:

```
$('.table').on( 'draw.dt', function() {
    table.clear().draw();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `relayout` on interval utilizing the [fixedColumns().relayout()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/fixedColumns().relayout()) API

```
setTimeout(
  function()
  {
    $.fn.dataTable.tables( { visible: false, api: true } ).columns.adjust().fixedColumns().relayout();
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: Where exactly do you put this function? in initComplete or drawCallback?

Comment: I tried the timeout function in `$('.table').on( 'draw.dt', function() {` and I see that something is happening with the fixed table after the timeout, but there is still a display problem

Comment: If you remove the scrolling does it align correctly ?

Comment: Everytime a change the pagination I get an overlay again of the table. I think that somehow  the table is dublicated again and again. Maybe it has to be removed somehow before reinitialized

Comment: `FixedHeader` is officialy not supported with either `scrollX` nor `scrollY`. Maybe there is some sort of compatibility problem with the `fixedColumn` and the scrollers as well.

Comment: But your code made it actually look a little bit better... So there is some improvement. Just it is not perfect yet. Do you have another idea?

Comment: You can try modifying the actual CSS of DataGrid, either from inside my function with jQuery or in general from outside in Pure CSS, like for example `.DTFC_RightBodyLiner{
overflow-x: hidden; }`